# Angular 4 : Adding routes dynamically after a promise

Tags: angular

I am trying to config my routes after a call has been done in the `ngInit` of my `AppComponent`

Here is my `app.component.ts`

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  entryComponents: [
    DummyComponent
  ]
})
export class AppComponent {
    routesLoaded: boolean = false
    constructor(private router: Router) {
        myCall().subscribe(() => {
            router.resetConfig([
                {
                    path: '', redirectTo: '/dummy', pathMatch: 'full'
                },
                {
                    path: 'dummy', component: DummyComponent
                }]
            )
            this.routesLoaded = true
        })
    }
}
```

and in my app.component.html

```
<div *ngIf="routesLoaded">
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

It doesn't work, and I am having the following error :

```
core.es5.js:1020 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): [object Object]
    at resolvePromise (zone.js:824)
    at resolvePromise (zone.js:795)
    at zone.js:873
    at ZoneDelegate.webpackJsonp.../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:425)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.es5.js:3881)
    at ZoneDelegate.webpackJsonp.../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:424)
    at Zone.webpackJsonp.../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.runTask (zone.js:192)
    at drainMicroTaskQueue (zone.js:602)
    at <anonymous>
```

Is what I am trying to do feasible ? Or did I just miss something ? 
If I move the `router.resetConfig` outside of the call, it works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

You should call `resetConfig` on `ngOnInit` function without delay.

you can use `APP_INITIALIZER` provider for resolving promises ( before module init ).
for example:

```
providers: [
    DataService,
    {
    provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
    useFactory: factory,
    deps: [DataService],
    multi: true
  }],
```

and `factory` function with `myCall` promise:

```
export function factory(dataService: DataService) {
  return () =>  dataService.myCall().then((_result) => {
    dataService.myCallResult = _result;
  })
}
```

`ngOnInit` will call after promise resolved.

```
 ngOnInit() {
    this.myCallResult = this.dataService.myCallResult; //promise result
    this.router.resetConfig([
      {
        path: '', redirectTo: '/dummy', pathMatch: 'full'
      },
      {
        path: 'dummy', component: DummyComponent
      }
    ]);
  }
```

check my example here:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bu8evj?file=app%2Fapp.component.html

Answer (score -1):

You should use a guard( `canActivate` ) .
`resetConfig` should have been called before you getting the route (in the guard).

Comment: I am a bit confused, what should I guard here since I don't have any routes set up ?

Comment: You are right. my bad. did you import RouterModule.forRoot([]) ? if you call resetConfig on ngOnInitit will work fine. you can use APP_INITIALIZER provider for resolving promises

Comment: I didn't know about the APPI_INITIALIZER. I am gonna give it a go tonight !

Comment: Do you need example?

Comment: Yes please sire.

Comment: OK, With pleasure